# Staking pool for native coins

Tags: solidity, web3js

I wanna build a staking pool for native coins like trx to test my skills as an engineer and yet due to my limited knowledge I don't know how to make a staking platform without creating a new token. Is it possible? if so, how? anything noticeable?

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about the blockchain's native asset, you can't mint those. So if the staking reward is in the native asset, somebody (probably you) have to be inserting those into the contract. Otherwise it can behave pretty much like regular token staking.

The code could be something like:

```
contract Staking {
    mapping(address => uint256) stakes;

    function stake() public payable {
        stakes[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }    

    function distributeRewards() public payable {
        // Distribute msg.value to stakers
    }
   
    ...
}
```